# Get GitHub commit contributions from commits to Azure DevOps repository

Tags: github, azure-devops

My wish is to have the contributions I make to a repo in Azure DevOps show up on my GitHub profile.

Is there a way to link this up properly?

The email I use for credentials when authenticating towards Azure DevOps is different than my GitHub connected email.

I have tried to use the same credentials for both but to no avail. Maybe I'm missing something.

Hopefully, someone out there has got this working.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: just to understand, you want to sync repo changes from azure devops to your github. so each time you make a commit or change on azure devops, it should sync with your github. Is that correct?

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Not quite. The repo changes in itself is not really of importance. Just that my GitHub contributions graph on my profile gets credited when I push a change to the Azure DevOps repo. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No. If you want your activity to show as GitHub contributions, the work has to be in a repository hosted in GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should understand that GitHub and Azure DevOps are independent systems. Azure DevOps has provided some functions e.g REST API,UI function to get repository from GitHub. But It’s a one-way data transfer from GitHub to Azure DevOps.

There is no supported REST API or UI functions that can sync repo changes from to Azure DevOps to your GitHub according  DevOps documents at present.

I am afraid that your GitHub contributions graph can’t get credited when you push a change to the Azure DevOps repo.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case, unfortunately. I was maybe hoping a bride had been built since both products are owned by the same company. I'll accept this one, thanks